# EF many-to-many with composite key only gets one left and one right key on the join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this model that has a composite key made from 3 different keys.  When it creates a many-to-many join table `DomainGroupDomainGroup`, I get only two keys.  One left, one right.  It references the field `Key`, which is really just a `ToLower()` of the distinguished name.  The only problem is there could be many `Domains` or `DomainScans` which would create collisions in primary keys, so we need both the `DomainscanId` and the `DomainId` to even identify which row we're actually talking about.  Not to mention, I doubt it would even let me collide without an error.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DomainGroupDomainGroup] (
    [DomainGroup_Key]  NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [DomainGroup_Key1] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DomainGroupDomainGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DomainGroup_Key] ASC, [DomainGroup_Key1] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.DomainGroupDomainGroup_dbo.DomainGroup_DomainGroup_Key] FOREIGN KEY ([DomainGroup_Key]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DomainGroup] ([Key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.DomainGroupDomainGroup_dbo.DomainGroup_DomainGroup_Key1] FOREIGN KEY ([DomainGroup_Key1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DomainGroup] ([Key])
);
```

Here's the model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Server.DomainTools.Controller.Domain.Model
{
    public class DomainGroup
    {

        public virtual ICollection<DomainUser> DomainUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DomainGroup> DomainGroups { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DomainGroup> Parents { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DomainScan")]
        public int DomainScanId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Domain")]
        public int DomainId { get; set; }

        //Composite primary key
        //DomainScanId is the version
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public DomainScan DomainScan { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Domain Domain { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that the composite key is not being respected at all.